# Check if elements has\belongs to the same parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have another question.
For example we have an HTML:

```
<div id="imageDiv>
<a id="testA">
    <img alt="" src "" id="img1">
    <img alt="" src "" id="img2">
    <img alt="" src "" id="img3">
    <img alt="" src "" id="img4">
    <img alt="" src "" id="img5">
</a>
    <img alt="" src "" id="img6">
</div>
```

How can I check, from the lowest level and, if it possible ,with simple JQuery selector or extension, that images with id`s 1 to 5 has same parent, but not image with 6th id.

In another words: how to check if images with id`s 1 to 5 are siblings()?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @Tushar Not only #img1, but #img1-5...

Comment: Take the item's parent's children, check if it includes the element you're interested in.

Comment: @artm
It will have a huge complexity and very inefficient, I will have to check if such condition exists for every image

Comment: @Tushar two jQuery object are never 'equal' unlike DOM node, e.g: `$('#img1')[0].parentNode === $('#img5')[0].parentNode`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/t324Lwoy/1/

```
function areSiblings(e1, e2){
    return $(e1).parent().children().is($(e2));
};

console.log(areSiblings("#img1", "#img3"));
console.log(areSiblings("#img2", "#img5"));
console.log(areSiblings("#img1", "#img6"));
```

Update:

or

```
function areSiblings(e1, e2){
    return $(e1).siblings().is($(e2));
};
```

Comment: Is there is a way to do same function and pass array of elements??

Comment: Instead of `.parent().children()` use `.siblings()`

Comment: @AlexBerd what kind of array are you planning to pass?  can you give an example of your usage?

Comment: @artm A.wolff
Thanks guys for you help

Comment: @AlexBerd I saw your edit to my answer but if you call your updated solution with `areSiblings(["#img1", "#img3"]);`, passing in an array, it won't work. So please review your edit and make sure you include a working solution together with how to call the new function.